Spacing between items in `enumerate`
I have the following code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{Examples}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{examples}\leavevmode
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\arabic*),leftmargin=0.75cm]
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
 \item Item 3
 \item Item 4
 \item Item 5
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{examples}
 \end{document}

which produces the following output

I need to remove the spacing between item 1 of the list and Examples 0.1 but at the same time I want to keep the spacing between the items themselves (that is, I need also to keep the little spacing between item 1, item 2, ... ). How to achieve this?
Also, is there an alternative to move the labels of the items ((1),(2),(3),...) to get precisely under the letter E of Examples 0.1 rather than using the command \leftmargin=0.75cm ?

With enumitem: topsep=0pt and labelindent=0pt.

labelindent=0pt does shift the label to the far left to be aligned under the word Example.
topsep=0pt is what I'm looking for regarding the first problem.

The enumitem package has many options. The following picture, taken from the enumitem manual (p. 3) gives some lengths definitions.

As the space before the list is mainly \topsep, use topsep=0pt to remove it.
The key left=<labelindent> .. <leftmargin> is a quicky way to set the position of the label and the position of the text. In your case, use simply left=0pt.
Full example:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{Examples}

\begin{document}

\begin{examples}\leavevmode
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\arabic*), topsep=0pt, left=0pt]
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
   \item Item 3
   \item Item 4
   \item Item 5
  \end{enumerate}
\end{examples}

\end{document}



Unfortunately, I'm using Latex version  3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (taken from cmd). When I added left=0pt an error has been shown.

@HusseinEid What is the version of the enumitem package? You can find it in the log (for example, I have a line with Package: enumitem 2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists).

Package: enumitem 2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
Is it possible to update it even if I don't has MikTex console?

@HusseinEid Maybe the best is to update your packages. Your distribution is ten years old.

How can I update if I do not have MixTex console?. Do you mean removing the old one and downloading a new version?

@HusseinEid Sorry I don't use MikTeX. I can't help you. But your pdflatex version corresponds to TexLive2014. It's pretty old.

Excuse me, what are the alternatives of MixTeX?

@HusseinEid There is TeXLive for example. But you should first try to update your MikTeX distribution.

I don't have console because my version is old (the console tool is newer than my version).

I'd recommend Overleaf until you sort out the local version. If your document is not too long, you should be able to compile it using just a free version. Note there is time limit until you buy subscription.
