Adjust the label in tasks environment in exam document class
I have the following simple minimal working example:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
  \question If $A=\Bigl\lbrace \emptyset, \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace, \bigl\lbrace 
   \emptyset \bigr\rbrace \Bigr\rbrace$, then

 \begin{tasks}(2)
  \task $A \cap \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace = \lbrace \lbrace \emptyset 
   \rbrace\rbrace$,  
  \task $\bigl\lbrace \emptyset, \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace \bigr\rbrace \subseteq 
   P(A)$, 
  \task $|P(A)| =16$,
  \task None of the previous.
 \end{tasks}
\end{questions}
\end{document}

Everything is fine except I need the label of the choices to be like (a), (b), and so on rather than a), b), and so on. How can I achieve this?

The standard way to achieve your goal should be
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} % amsfonts is loaded by amssymb
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{
  label=(\alph*),
  label-width=1.5em,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question If $A=\bigl\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}, \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\}$, then
  \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $A \cap \{ \emptyset \} = \bigl\{ \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\}$,
    \task $\bigl\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\} \subseteq P(A)$,
    \task $|P(A)| =16$,
    \task None of the previous.
  \end{tasks}
\end{questions}

\end{document}


I've made the brace sizes more consistent. Using \{...\} instead of \lbrace...\rbrace is optional, but in my opinion clearer.
You however appear to be using an older TeX distribution (likely TeX Live 2018 or earlier). You should upgrade. If you can't, you can replace the \settasks instruction with
\settasks{
  counter-format=(tsk[a]),
  label-width=1.5em,
}


Excuse me @egreg, How can I get the version of my Tex and how can I upgrade?

Should I delete the current version and install a newer one?

@HusseinEid It highly depends on what operating system and TeX distribution you're using.

I'm using Miktex on Windows 10.

@HusseinEid Do a full reinstall.

Is it necessary also to reinstall texmaker?@egreg

@HusseinEid I believe it isn’t.

You can change the task label like this:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{
  label=(\alph*),
  label-width=1.5em
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
  \question If $A=\Bigl\lbrace \emptyset, \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace, \bigl\lbrace 
   \emptyset \bigr\rbrace \Bigr\rbrace$, then

 \begin{tasks}(2)
  \task $A \cap \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace = \lbrace \lbrace \emptyset 
   \rbrace\rbrace$,  
  \task $\bigl\lbrace \emptyset, \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace \bigr\rbrace \subseteq 
   P(A)$, 
  \task $|P(A)| =16$,
  \task None of the previous.
 \end{tasks}
\end{questions}
\end{document}



Why does the code throw an exception 'Missing number, treated as 0' with me?

I don't get an exception. Is your tex installation up-to-date?

@HusseinEid Likely because you have an older TeX distribution. I get the error you mention with TeX Live 2018.

No.
Is \settasks part of tasks environment?

@HusseinEid It works fine with texlive 2024. You should really update if your still using this ancient version https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/714632/spacing-between-items-in-enumerate#comment1776454_714637

@HusseinEid See https://tug.org/texlive/ for instructions how to get a current texlive

If you have already upgraded your TeX distribution, here is an alternative version using the new enumext package without using the exam class:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{enumext}

\setenumext[keyans*]
  {
    label=(\alph*),
    columns=2,
    labelwidth=1.5em,
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumext}[save-ans=test,show-ans=true]
  \item If $A=\bigl\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}, \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\}$, then
  \begin{keyans*}
    \item* $A \cap \{ \emptyset \} = \bigl\{ \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\}$,
    \item $\bigl\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\} \subseteq P(A)$,
    \item $|P(A)| =16$,
    \item None of the previous.
  \end{keyans*}

  \item If $A=\bigl\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}, \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\}$, then
  \begin{keyans*}
    \item $|P(A)| =16$,
    \item None of the previous.
    \item* $A \cap \{ \emptyset \} = \bigl\{ \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\}$,
    \item $\bigl\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \bigr\} \subseteq P(A)$,
  \end{keyans*}
\end{enumext}

% print
\printkeyans{test}

\end{document}


